# How can an Administrator Discreetly View a Remote Desktop User's Session?

Tags: windows-server-2003, monitoring, windows-terminal-services

I have a manager that has legitimate reasons for wanting to view a user's Remote Desktop session with Windows 2003 server.

Logged into that same server (as Administrator), how can you discreetly view a regular user's Remote Desktop Session?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set the Remote Control settings to view the session with the "Require user's permission" checkbox unchecked. You can set this setting on both the user account and the RDP protocol on the server but the server setting over-rides the user account setting. Also make sure this isn't being set to a conflicting setting via GPO. When the manager "connects" to the user's session the user will see a very brief blip of the screen but otherwise won't know that someone is shadowing their session.

Answer (score 3):

Just found an answer for this and tested it. I Hope it will help someone else. Here is part taken from the Source.

[...]

2. Type `quser.exe` to determine the session number of the user session you want to shadow.
3. In this example, the Administrator is going to shadow the user1 session which is session 3. You need to know the session number (“3”) for the next step.
4. Start shadow session by typing `mstsc /shadow:# /control` where # is the session number to shadow and /control allows you to control the session.

Source: https://www.riptidehosting.com/blog/how-to-shadow-a-users-remote-desktop-session-on-windows-2016-in-workgroup-mode/

Answer (score 0):

In my experience RDP will not work, because it will lock the current user's session to create another session for remote access by the admin. This is for remote sessions to a a workstation. For shadow sessions to a terminal server joeqwerty  is correct.

In a previous work place the managers used Atelier Web Remote Commander for this same purpose. I allowed viewing the desktop of a specific representative/agent without interrupting them. :-)

Comment: Can you explain your answer. You certainly can shadow an RDP session without locking the session.

Comment: @Darkmatter, I think you're confusing Remote Desktop as it applies to workstations with Terminal Services on a server (also called Remote Desktop). Maybe you should read the question again.

Comment: I was confusing it with server to workstation connection. Corrected. Thanks

Answer (score -4):

I don't think RDP allows this, but you could do it with [TightVNC](http://www.tightvnc.com/).  By default, TightVNC has a taskbar icon that changes color when someone connects (for privacy/security reasons).  To disable it, follow [this FAQ](http://www.tightvnc.com/faq.php#hideicon).

Note that TightVNC requires TCP port 5900 to be open on the server.

Comment: RDP absolutely supports this, and installing VNC on a terminal server is, well, odd

Comment: In my opinion your feedback is not constructive. It would help if you explained how to do this with RDP rather than merely saying that it's supported, and why installing VNC is odd. (Other than it's unnecessary in light of RDP's support for this...) In any case thanks for the correction. RDP is more powerful than I thought.

Comment: I didn't feel the need to point out its possibilities as JoeQwerty has done a good job of this in his answer above. Installing VNC on a terminal server is odd as it provides no benefit to a full terminal server, as on Windows it generally only provides console access.

Comment: @Philip, if you feel that Marks' comment is not constructive you're going to feel uncomfortable around here. Most of us will simply downvote such an answer (as I have done) without even telling you why. In this case I'll make an exception. I downvoted you because the answer shows a lack of understanding of RDP (which is after all merely a protocol) or Remote Desktop. It also shows you didn't read the question properly.